# How to set objects property not at the same place?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I have some model, lets say:

```
export interface Car {
  driverId: string;
  driverName: string;
  color: string;
}
```

In my function I want to return an an array of objects from this model, but I can only build it after few async calls that is happening in this function, so I wanted to declare an empty array of this model and assign the relevant properties as I have them:

```
  public getListOfCarObjects(): Car[]  {
    let listOfCars: Car[] = [];
    self._serviceOne.getIds().subscribe(
      (res: DriversInfo) => {
        res.ids.map((id: string, idIndex: number) => {
          listOfCars[idIndex].driverId = id;
          // more stuff api calls below and building the object
          ...
  }
```

but im getting this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'driverId' of undefined

how, should I do something like this?

thanks!!

Comment: You never set `listOfCars` to anything other than an empty array `[]`.  `listOfCars = []` at the time you request `listOfCars[idIndex]`.

Comment: How is this data coming back? In most cases, if you are getting an array of data back it will automatically create your array and you don't need to try to initialize it first.

Comment: @axlj exactly, so how can I solve it?

Comment: As @DeborahK alluded to, you need to acquire the data from the service.  `_serviceOne` is a pretty non descriptive name but I assume it returns Driver Info.  Do you have another service that acquires cars? Maybe you need to be calling that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the object instance at the index you are referencing. You could create it when you receive the data, either by pushing the value or setting it by index:

```
listOfCars.push({ driverId: id, dirverName: "", color: "" });
listOfCars[idIndex] = { driverId: id, dirverName: "", color: "" };
```

Since your interface specifies that all properties are required you have to specify them all when creating the new object, as I did above. If you what to create `Cars` with only anid you can mark the rest of the properties as optional:

```
export interface Car {
  driverId: string;
  driverName?: string;
  color?: string;
}
```

Comment: its important for me to keep the order, so at this point i have the ids, and after that I will another api call to get something else of this id, so I need to keep the index, otherwise I dont understand how this will work..

Comment: You can always find your driver in the array using the `driverId`, which I assume is unique. So you don't need to keep track of the index.

Comment: Added a version that uses the index, I thought it best to  make sure the array indices are contiguous (as the would using push) but you can set the value by index as well.